# Why does my Custom XML RPC get-config not work?

Tags: xml, rpc, cisco

I am trying to write my own RPC to get-config. I know there is a build in get-config, but want to experiment with my own. However it is not working and i get this error. Can anyone help?

```
Command: $ netconf-console --host ios-xe-mgmt.cisco.com --port 10000 --user developer --password C1sco12345 --rpc get-config.xml
```

get-config.xml contents:

```
<rpc xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="1">
  <get-config>
    <source>
      <running/>
    </source>
  </get-config>
</rpc>
```

Returned result:

```
<rpc-error xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
<error-type>protocol</error-type>
<error-tag>operation-not-supported</error-tag>
<error-severity>error</error-severity>
<error-info><bad-element>rpc</bad-element>
</error-info>
</rpc-error>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removal of rpc and xmlns works for this.

Therefore, the RPC sent only needs to be:

```
  <get-config>
    <source>
      <running/>
    </source>
  </get-config>
```